# How to seperate out group concat results

Tags: mysql

I am using Group concat in aggregate function in my project to display subcategories of a categories.

This is MYSQL query.

```
$sql_query = "SELECT TC.category_name, GROUP_CONCAT(TS.sub_category_name ORDER BY TS.sub_category_name)  from table_categories as TC
    INNER JOIN
    table_subcategory_categories as TSC
    ON
    TSC.category_id = TC.category_id

    INNER JOIN
    table_subcategories as TS
    ON
    TS.sub_categories_id = TSC.subcategory_id

    GROUP BY TC.category_id
    order by TC.category_name";
```

The Problem is i need to process these subcategories as separate entities. But Because of Group concat they becomes a single entity.

What is the solution for this?

Is there any alternative of Group concat to achieve the same.

Current:

```
Body Wash           <a>Bathing Soap|Shower Gel</a>  delete
```

This delete makes no sense here.

Expecting:

```
Body Wash           <a>Bathing Soap</a>   delete
                    <a>Shower Gel</a>     delete
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Where does <a> and delete come from

Answer (score 0):

So why not just remove the `GROUP_CONCAT`...?

```
$sql_query = "SELECT TC.category_name, TS.sub_category_name
from table_categories as TC
INNER JOIN
table_subcategory_categories as TSC
ON
TSC.category_id = TC.category_id

INNER JOIN
table_subcategories as TS
ON
TS.sub_categories_id = TSC.subcategory_id

order by TC.category_name, TS.sub_category_name";
```

Comment: we can do that. But this will display two or more rows depending on the number of subcategory in category. I need only one row to be displayed for each category.

Comment: But there is 2 rows in your example...?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `group by`:

```
select TC.category_name, TS.sub_category_name
from table_categories TC INNER JOIN
    table_subcategory_categories TSC
    ON TSC.category_id = TC.category_id INNER JOIN
    table_subcategories TS
    ON TS.sub_categories_id = TSC.subcategory_id
order by TC.category_name, TS.sub_category_name;
```

You are going to get the values in multiple rows.  You will also get `category_name` repeated in each row.  That is how SQL result sets work.  If you don't want the category repeated, then do something on the application side to get the results you want.